# How to adjust the text in a textbox in wp7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

In my app, what i want is when the text goes beyond the width of the text box, i want it to mention it somehow to the user,(either by placing ... at the end or decreasing the font size so that it fits the text box).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text ellipsis..try this..

```
<TextBlock  Name="txtFeedTitle"
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to do so

First one is :
Set  TextWrapping property of TextBox to Wrap, Remove Height Property of textbox and set Width Propert of TextBox To some definite size (200).

Second is :
Use following style on textbox. It enable scrolling in textbox control

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>    
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="AppTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" >
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderBrush="#e64358" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0,5" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FF71B68D" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#e64358"/>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<TextBox  Style="{StaticResource AppTextBoxStyle}" Width = "300"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You Could use this for assigning a particular length of string

   ```
   String str="aaaaaaaaa"; 
   textBoxName.Text = str.Substring(0, 5) + "...";
   ```
2. You could use `TextWrapping` property of textBox cintrol

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="AppTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">

                    <Border BorderThickness='1'
                      Background='#ffefefef'
                      BorderBrush='LightBlue'>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                           Margin='4,1' />
                    </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42"
         Margin="40,177,0,0"
         Text="TextBox with long text to show Text ellipsis"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184"
         Style="{StaticResource AppTextBoxStyle}" />
```